# How to make decision in onClick

Tags: android, onclick

This is for searching the word on the `TextView`

```
 public void viewWord(View view)
    {

        score = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourScore);
        tv2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        tv3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv3);
        searchWord = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.searchWord);
        wordList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.wordList);
        text = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.textHere);
        wordList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.wordList);

      //SearchWord in AutoCompleteTextView text
      //Display equivalent score of word in TextView score
        String s1= search.getText().toString();
        String s2= dbHelper.getData(s1);
        score.setText(s2);
        tv2.setText(s2);
        tv3.setText(s2);

      //Get data from textview      
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<String>());
        wordList.setAdapter(adapter);       
        adapter.add(text.getText().toString());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        text.setText("");
        add();


    }

    public void add (){
        x = Integer.parseInt(tv2.getText().toString());
        y = Integer.parseInt(tv3.getText().toString());
        z = x + y;
        score.setText(Double.toString(z));
    }
```

In my app, I am using an `ImageView` to search the word and display the score. I am having a hard time in displaying the score using 1 `TextView` so I decided to make it 2. I want my `ImageView` to function like this:

```
if(onMyImageViewFirstClick){
display the score on textview1
}
else{
if(onMyImageViewSecondClick){
display the score on textview2
}
```

how can i do it this way?  Any suggestions will be highly appreciated :)

Note: I am new in android programming. I would appreciate if you'll also help me with the codes

Comment: Create an `int` variable as a counter and increment it when the button is clicked and check the number in your `if/else`?

Comment: can you help me code it? this is my first app so i'm not really that good on constructing codes

Comment: Do you mean 2 consecutive clicks on the `ImageButton`?

Comment: yes, but does it makes difference if i wanted it more than 2? because my taget if atleast 10 consecutive clicks(if thats possible) by the way, clicks are made after putting words on the textview.

Comment: Please show all of the code for your `OnClickListener`. It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: i edited my question. codes are provided above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with a class variable changin his value between 0 - 1, for example:

```
private int optionTxtView = 0

    imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1); 
            imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                   if(optionTxtView == 0){
                     //display the score on textview1
                    optionTxtView = 1;
                   }else{
                     //display the score on textview2    
                   optionTxtView = 0;
                   }
                }
            });
```

or you can use a **boolean** value (suggested by @mapo)

```
    private boolean optionTxtView;

        imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1); 
                imageButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                       if(optionTxtView){
                         //display the score on textview1
                        optionTxtView = false;
                       }else{
                         //display the score on textview2    
                       optionTxtView = true;
                       }
                    }
                });
```

So, according to your code, the solution must be:

```
     //declare a boolean variable
private int optionTxtView = 0  

     public void viewWord(View view)  {
    ...
    ...
    ...
          //SearchWord in AutoCompleteTextView text
          //Display equivalent score of word in TextView score
            String s1= search.getText().toString();
            String s2= dbHelper.getData(s1);
            score.setText(s2);

                   if(optionTxtView == 0){
                         //display the score on textview1
                        tv2.setText(s2);
                        optionTxtView = 1;
                   }else{
                         //display the score on textview2    
                         tv3.setText(s2);
                       optionTxtView = 0;
                   }
    ...
    ...
    ...
        }
```

Comment: why not using boolean?

Comment: I have my question edited i included the code i am using .. can you help me solve my problem using those code?

Comment: I'm sorry typographical error its supposed to be ImageView.
I declare it on my xml as android:onClick="viewWord".
I hope you can understand me.

Comment: @Elenasys It's not working . Please see the image above

Comment: On the first click it should be on the second textview and the second click should be on the 3rd textview.

I need it to do that way because i will add them both and display the sum in the first textview

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can implement a click counter.

Note how you reset the counter when a total of 2 clicks are registered. Once that happens the counter starts over and again will first affect `tv1` and then `tv2`.

```
// Find TextViews before (so you don't have to repeat this expensive operation)
final TextView tv1 = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
final TextView tv2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    int numberOfClicks = 0;

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        ++numberOfClicks;
        if(numberOfClicks < 2){
            tv1.setText("Some text");
        } else if(numberOfClicks >= 2){
            tv1.setText("Some other text");
            // Reset the click counter
            numberOfClicks = 0;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I have my code above can you help me with that one?